# UITableView Delegates are not getting called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, delegates

I am creating a view at runtime and adding a UITableView as its subview.
I have also defined the delegate of the tableview to self .

But still the UITableView Delegates are not getting called

@interface cViewController : UIViewController

```
RouteShowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[RouteShowView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 410) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
table.delegate = self;
UIButton * Go = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
Go.frame = CGRectMake(0, 4, 70, 42);
[Go setTitle:@"<< BACK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Go addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[Go setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[RouteShowView addSubview:table];
[RouteShowView addSubview:Go];

[self.view addSubview:RouteShowView];
```

Comment: I'm guessing because a `UITableView`'s `datasource` is more important and it is required. Try with `table.datasource=self.` and don't forget to add methods `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: no luck for this also :(

Comment: @WakkaoW No luck with trying datasource also ?

Comment: @iNoob   Yes, Still no luck .....but thanks datasource is needed any way.
But still numberOfRowsInSection is not getting called

Comment: @WakkaoW, that is weird. I just tried with including datasource and returning number of rows as 3. Though i tried it for `self.view addSubView:table` instead of your `RouteShowView `.

Comment: cleaning and recompiling did the trick  :D  

so Datasource was what I was missing.  Thnx  iNoob

Comment: @WakkaoW, Ah nice to know :D Good luck, or i would be puzzled whole day about it

Comment: @WakkaoW, what is "no luck"? the software developer is not about luck. post your full code and we will find where you've made mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing things are

```
//.h file
@interface SimpleTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
}
@end

// in .m file
table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 410) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

// set delegated object
table. delegate = self;

// set source for data
table.dataSource = self;
```

And implement @required protocols which are defined under documentation of UITableView

```
@protocol UITableViewDataSource<NSObject>

@required

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you added **UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource** in your **.h** file... i think you missed this code in your **.m** file

```
table.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

First try checking the delegates methods by code completion on xcode, If you obtained proper delegates into your class, xcode automatically detects your delegate methods.

I guess you may not be declare

```
@interface SimpleTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```